# Trying to change the value of a global variable

Tags: jquery, variables

I have this code trying to change the global variable `ipad`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    "use strict";
    var ipad=0;
    var android=0;
    var windows=0;

    $("#ipad").click(function() {
        ipad=10;
        android=0;
        windows=0;
        $("#ipad").css('background-color','#C30');
        $("#android").css('background-color','#0C0');
        $("#windows").css('background-color','#0C0');
        $("#not_important").css('background-color','#0C0');
    });

    document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = ipad;
});
```

But when I click on the `ipad` button, I can't get the desired result (10). Could anyone tell, please tell me where am I going wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Btw, `ipad` is not really global. It's still in the scope of your `ready` function

Answer (score 0):

You have a #iPad click handler which changes the value of the iPad variable but your following code is not within the same handler

```
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = ipad;
```

So your element "res" value will be initial value which is "0",

if you want to set value of this element after click then copy that line of code in to click handler too.

```
$("#ipad").click(function(){
            ipad=10;
            android=0;
            windows=0;
           $("#ipad").css('background-color','#C30');
            $("#android").css('background-color','#0C0');
           $("#windows").css('background-color','#0C0');
           $("#not_important").css('background-color','#0C0');
           document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = ipad;
    });
```

Here is Jsfiddle [example](https://jsfiddle.net/mtechdev/hvhopvk8/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks but I want ipad var to remain global because I want to add this value to another value later. how can I fix this? Any additional help?

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
document.getElementById("res").innerHTML = ipad;
```

is running when the document is ready, before you click the ipad button, i.e.: the click handler didn't run yet (it will run when you click the button), so the `ipad` variable, at the time you set it as the html content of  `res`, is still 0.

a simple solution would be to put that line inside the handler.

Comment: thanks but I want ipad var to remain global because I want to add this value to another value later. how can I fix this? Any additional help?

Comment: `ipad` would still be "global"(in the scope of the ready function) because it was defined outside the click handler. You just have to be careful and work with the variable when you know the right value has been set (i.e.: when you know for sure the user already clicked `#ipad`).